# How can I populate a texbox with a date retireved from SQL server? I get the message, " cannot explicitly convert form stirng to system datetime

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

How can I populate a texbox with a date retireved from SQL server?  I get the message

> cannot explicitly convert form string to system datetime.

I am trying this:

```
string getEffectiveDate = from v in dt.vw_AMLI_Participants
                          where v.SSN == getSSNNow && v.CustomerID == 56
                          select v.EffectiveDate.ToString;
```

Comment: Are you sure this is where you are getting the error?

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a couple of issues with your query. As stated by someone else, you are missing the parenthesis from your `ToString()` method call. The second issue is that the query will return `IQueryable<string>` and you are trying to assign it to a `string`. If you are running under the assumption that your query will always return a single result, try the following:

```
string getEffectiveDate = (from v in dt.vw_AMLI_Participants
                      where v.SSN == getSSNNow && v.CustomerID == 56
                      select v.EffectiveDate.ToString()).Single();
```

If that is still giving you problems (which it may because the Linq provider may not know how to interprerate `v.EffectiveDate.ToString()`), then try the following:

```
string getEffectiveDate = (from v in dt.vw_AMLI_Participants
                      where v.SSN == getSSNNow && v.CustomerID == 56
                      select v.EffectiveDate).Single().ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to write `ToString()` (notice you left out the parenthesis).

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the toString:

```
string getEffectiveDate = from v in dt.vw_AMLI_Participants 
    where v.SSN == getSSNNow && v.CustomerID == 56 select v.EffectiveDate;
```